# How to install specific version 3.3.1 of R in CentOS

Tags: r, centos, libcurl

I'm tring to install R_3.3.1 in CentOS.
So i download tar file and build it.
During build this file i got some erros because of the defendency.
I solve this errors by reference.
https://oguya.ch/posts/2017-03-18-building-R-on-rhel-6/ here.

But At the libcurl step.I can't solve it.

```
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

and My curl version is 7.47.1 so i think version is not matter

```
[nubiz@localhost R-3.3.1]$ curl --version
curl 7.47.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.1 zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
```

but the error say this libcurl can't use http.

So is there any version can use http or something way to this error?

I check my protocols what can i use in curl using this command 'curl-config --protocols'

And i can using only HTTP like this

```
DICT
FILE
FTP
GOPHER
HTTP
IMAP
POP3
RTSP
SMTP
TELNET
TFTP
```

it can be enable to HTTPS?

Comment: Which CentOS version do you use? Instead of following that blog I would first try to install libraries with development packages as provided by CentOS.

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6.9 version.
you mean that install the development package. like 'Development Tolls'?
if you mean this. i'm already install that.

Comment: I don't mean 'Development Tools', but install `libcurl-devel` and not only `libcurl` (as an example). However, `libcurl` from CentOS 6.9 is probably to old. In that case you have to configure `libcurl` for SSL support, probably by installing `openssl-devel` first and running `./configure` for `libcurl` again, c.f. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html.

Comment: As you told. I'm tring to build curl with ssl.
So i install openssl in $HOME/apps/openssl/1.1.0 and build curl by this commend.


    env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/nubiz/apps/openssl/1.1.0/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --with-ssl --prefix=/home/nubiz/apps/curl/7.47.1/

but i failed to build.. 
with this error 


make[2]: *** [libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nubiz/curl-7.47.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nubiz/curl-7.47.1/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1


I'm trying to solve this error but.. it's hard :l

Comment: It is impossible to tell anything from that error message excerpt. Do you have to install in `$HOME`, or could you also install in, e.g., `/usr/local/`?

Comment: I installed all the program for build R in /home/usr/apps.